# Unable to transfer Data from table to another mysql php angular

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i want to transfer data from table infos to table archived , but when i click the submit button nothing happening

this is my submit button  :

```
<button type="button" ng-click="move(name.id)" class="btn btn-info btn-l">Submit</button>
```

and this is my Angularjs code :

```
$scope.move = function(id){
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to move it?"))        
{
$http({
method:"POST",
url:"insert.php",
data:{'id':id, 'action':'move'}

    }).success(function(data){
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.error = false;
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.fetchData();
        }); 
    }
};
```

---

this is my php code in insert.php :

```
include('database_connection.php');

$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$error = '';
$message = '';
$validation_error = '';
$first_name = '';
$last_name = '';

if($form_data->action == "move")
{
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO archived
    SELECT * FROM infos
    DELETE FROM infos
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $output['message'] = 'Data moved';
    }
}
```

when i edit my query to look like that :

```
$query = "
DELETE FROM infos
";
```

everything works fine and the data in the the table infos will be deleted !!

so can anyone tell me what i'm missing or what i'm doing wrong ?

thank you and if you need more infos about my code just ask which part you want to know

Answer (score 1):

You query is incorrect;

```
INSERT INTO archived
SELECT * FROM infos
DELETE FROM infos
```

To execute two queries, you need to add a semicolon in between statements when in editor or command line.

```
INSERT INTO archived SELECT * FROM infos; DELETE FROM infos;
```

However, prepared statement can only execute one MySQL query. You can prepare as many statements as you want in different variables:

```
$stmtCopy = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO archived SELECT * FROM infos");
$stmtDelete = $sql->prepare("DELETE FROM infos");
```